# webbrowser method for webkit to retrieve attribute

Tags: c#, browser, webkit, getelementbyid

I'm trying to figure a way out off the following scenario:

I'm using c# to create a webbrowser for a specific use. When i'm using the webbrowser component in visual studio, i can use the following code:

```
public void clickSubmit()
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (HtmlElement hem in WebBrowser1.document.all)
                {
                    if (hem.GetAttribute("id").Contains("login"))
                    {
                        hem.InvokeMember("Click");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {

            }
        }
```

I want to write a method that provides the same functionallity BUT FOR WEBKIT.

For example the webrowser1.document.all is not a property for webkit.

Can somebody help me out here and write a function that could work.